# Django | Error al excluir en un filter

Tags: django

Estoy tratando de hacer un filter en object_list, excluyendo el objeto passedQuestionList
numberQuestion es una columna de modelo TestQuestion. Pero no toma la columna numberQuestion.

**Código:**

```
passedQuestionList=UserAnswers.objects.all().filter(modality__name=questionMod, user=username, correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion__gte=4)
        if questionMod:
            object_list = TestQuestion.objects.all().filter(nameModality__name=questionMod).order_by('number')[:10].exclude(number__in=passedQuestionList.numberQuestion)
```

**Error1:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error2:**

**'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'numberQuestion'**

**Models:**

```
class TestQuestion(models.Model):
    ANSWER=(('1','A'),('2','B'),('3','C'),('4','D'))
    number=models.IntegerField('Nº',null=True,blank=True)
    question=models.TextField('Pregunta',null=True,blank=True)
    a=models.TextField('A',null=True,blank=True)
    b=models.TextField('B',null=True,blank=True)
    c=models.TextField('C',null=True,blank=True)
    d=models.TextField('D',null=True,blank=True)
    answer=models.CharField('Respuesta',max_length=1,choices=ANSWER, null=True, blank=True)
    nameModality=models.ForeignKey(Modality,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    observations=models.TextField('Observaciones',null=True,blank=True)




class UserAnswers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    modality = models.ForeignKey(Modality,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    numberQuestion = models.IntegerField('Número pregunta',null=True,blank=True)
    correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion=models.IntegerField('Veces que se ha respondido una pregunta correctamente',null=True,blank=True)
    wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion=models.IntegerField('Veces que se ha respondido una pregunta incorrectamente',null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: ¡Hola, ret! Bueno, el error te dice todo, ¿no? Intenta primero colocando `exclude()` y por último haz el slicing (`[:10]`)

Comment: Gracias.Ya no devuelve ese error. Muchas gracias. ¿Por qué será que no reconoce la columna "numberQuestion" si es una de las columnas del modelo UserAnswers? Erro: "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'numberQuestion'" Un saludo.

Comment: Porque `passedQuestionList` es una queryset. No un objeto del modelo `UserAnswers`. Elimina `.all().filter` de esa línea, y sustituye eso por `.get`. **Ojo:** Si no existe un registro que cumpla con los criterios de búsqueda, al usar `get()` se levantará una excepción. Ten eso en cuenta.

Comment: Ok! ¿El get me servirá para filtrar o conseguir 10 filas de una tabla filtrando como quiera? Pensaba que para filtrar tenía que utilizar siempre filter. Un saludo.

Comment: Supongo que otro tipo de excepción es el que me ha salido: get() returned more than one TestQuestion -- it returned 15! Es curioso, ya que tenidnedon [10], indica que devuelve 15.

Comment: No, no, me refiero a que uses `get()` para obtener `passedQuestionList`.

Comment: Ok perdona, entendido. Gracias y perdona los pecados por ser novato. xD